# Test an XML document against an XSD, but allow certain sections to not be checked nor require an XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

There is an input file to a piece of software I am writing. This input file is XML. I wish to define an XSD schema for this input file. I have done so, and so far, everything is working well.

However, in this file, there should also be "arbitrary blocks of XML", which have no meaning for my application, and I need to write them through to the output file without modification. I would like to be able to **test** parts of the input file which are relevant for my application against my XSD, but **not** require my customer to write an XSD for the "arbitrary blocks of XML" which are only relevant for his application and not for mine. How can I specify this in the XSD file?

So far I've done the following:

- Define a namespace for those tags which are relevant for my application
- Create an XSD file which defines those tags within that namespace (i.e. which are relevant for my application)
- In my XSD file, use `<xs:any>` to state that at a certain point in my file, any tags supplied by the user may be present
- I have, for testing, chosen a tag for the "arbitrary block of XML", defined an XSD (no namespace) for that tag, and inserted it into the XML file, like `<test xmlns="" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="x"/>` and that works fine.

However, as soon as I don't put the schema location reference in the `<test>` tag the XSD validator complains it doesn't recognize the `<test>` tag as it's not in my main XSD, despite the fact that it's validating against the `<xs:any>` tag in the schema.

Is there any way to say to the XSD validator "this particular tag does not require any XSD to be present for any of its contents"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adrian, you're absolutely on a right track with usage of `<xs:any>` element. However you need to add last piece to the puzzle - define how content inside this element has to be validated.

By default validating parser will expect schema defined for this element and will fail validation if it's not available (or content is not valid according to this schema). In order to change behavior you need to specify attribute `<xs:any processContents="skip">`. Another option (maybe more preferable) is to specify `processContents="lax"` which means that parser will look for schema definition and if it's found it will use to validate the fragment but if it's not then it will ignore it.

More about this attribute you could find in [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#process_contents). Also there is quite helpful [article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2002/07/03/schema_design.html) on creating extensible schemas.